Adding vector of numbers at the end of a list in R
I'm new to R. I've been trying to add a vector to the end of a list in R but it doesn't seem to be working.
Here is what I tried:
L <- list("audrey", 19, TRUE)
L["new"] <- c(1,2,3)      # doesn't work

v1 <- c(1,2,3)
L["new"] <- v1            # doesn't work

Both of these code throw the same error, number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.
I expected both to work, as when creating a list, the following works:
J <- list("audrey", 19, TRUE, c(1,2,3))

v2 <- c(1,2,3)
K <- list("mary", 20, v2)

I assumed it would work because it seems that I am just appending a new vector to the end of my list with a named index. Now it seems like I would have to redefine the list in order to add a vector to the end?
Would appreciate explanations on why this throws an error, and if there is a way of achieving what I want to do without redefining the list. Thanks!

Try: L[["new"]] <- c(1,2,3) 

@Edward L[["new"]] <- c(1,2,3) worked! Thank you!

Try using double brackets instead of single ones.
L <- list("audrey", 19, TRUE)
L[["new"]] <- c(1,2,3)

This should work because single brackets are used to subset, while double brackets are used for extracting or replacing
I hope this helps

In addition to the method posted by @Edward and @Blessing (L1) here two other methods. The second uses c to combine two lists, and the third converts the vector first to a list before using single brackets:
L1 <- list("audrey", 19, TRUE)
L1[["new"]] <- c(1, 2, 3)

L2 <- list("audrey", 19, TRUE)
L2 <- c(L2, new = list(c(1, 2, 3)))

L3 <- list("audrey", 19, TRUE)
L3["new"] <- list(c(1, 2, 3))

